# how to get rid of - "warning: converting to non-pointer type 'char' from NULL"?

Tags: c++, warnings, opensuse

I have this block of code:

```
int myFunc( std::string &value )
{
    char buffer[fileSize];
    ....
    buffer[bytesRead] = NULL;
    value = buffer;
    return 0;
}
```

The line - buffer[bytes] = NULL is giving me a warning: converting to non-pointer type 'char' from NULL. How do I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Don't use `NULL`? It's generally reserved for pointers, and you don't have a pointer, only a simple `char`. Just use `\0` (null-terminator) or a simple `0`.

Answer (score 3):

`buffer[bytesRead] = 0;`  // NULL is meant for pointers

As a suggestion, if you want to avoid copying and all then, below can be considered.

```
int myFunc (std::string &value)
{
  s.resize(fileSize);
  char *buffer = const_cast<char*>(s.c_str());
  //...
  value[bytesRead] = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` ≠ `NUL`.

`NULL` is a constant representing a null pointer in C and C++.

`NUL` is the ASCII NUL character, which in C and C++ terminates strings and is represented as `\0`.

<strike>You can also use `0`, which is exactly the same as `\0`, since in C character literals have `int` type.</strike> In C++, character constants are type `char`.

Comment: The question is falsly tagged as `c`, since the code clearly uses a `std::string`, which is C++. As such, string literals aren't `int` but correctly `char`.

Comment: From your answer I atleast can see how the OP might have gotten to `NULL` for initializing the char.. thanks for that. xD

Comment: `NULL` is a null pointer in C.  In C++ you should use `nullptr`.